# Iterate over framesets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, frameset

How can I list all `FRAMESET` elements in an HTML document using JavaScript?  I believe it to be possible to select these elements in the DOM tree because the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622) plugin for Firefox is able to list all the `FRAMESETS` in a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames) collection, if that's what you mean.

EDIT:
Ah. For blowing away all `frameset` elements, [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

```
var framesets = document.getElementsByTagName('frameset');
for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
  // optional test for whether framesets[i]'s hatesFreedom attribute is true or false
  framesets[i].parentNode.removeChild(framesets[i]);
}
```

Or jQuery, obviously:

```
$('frameset[hatesFreedom=true]').remove();
```

Comment: No, I mean how do I select or list the `FRAMESET` elements in the document?  These are the container elements of `FRAME` or other `FRAMESET` elements.  One reason that I want to do this is in order to use JavaScript to remove a `FRAMESET` from a document.

Comment: wombleton, please have a crack at the related question that I asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791706/iterate-over-framesets-with-xpath-expression-in-javascript.

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{
 //window.top.frames[0]
 alert(for i in window.top.frames) {alert('window.top.frames = '+i);}
 alert(for i in window.top.frames[0]) {alert('window.top.frames[0] = '+i);}
}
catch (err)
{
 //top frame is not your domain, break out of frames.
 top.window.location = 'http://localhost/';
}
```