# Iterate over framesets with XPath expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, frameset, document.evaluate

Why does the following JavaScript, when run in Firefox 3.6.3, delete all `FRAMESET` elements in a document, but the similar script that instead uses an XPath expression to select the `FRAMESET` elements, does not?  Is `document.evaluate()` simply unable to match `FRAMESET` elements?  Is there an error in the XPath expression?  Is there some other error?

Select all `FRAMESET` elements using method `document.getElementsByTagName()` (succeeds):

```
var framesets = document.getElementsByTagName('frameset');
for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
  framesets[i].parentNode.removeChild(framesets[i]);
}
```

Select all `FRAMESET` elements using an XPath expression (fails):

```
var framesets = document.evaluate("//frameset", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
  framesets[i].parentNode.removeChild(framesets[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the XPathResult is iterator-ish. It does not have a length property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

`framesets.length` will be undefined. In short, Here Be Dragons.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Was just about to give a similar answer, but you beat me to it!

Comment: It would be good if you would copy the answer here, 'cuz that page no longer exists.